# Calling hg from Powershell with arguments in string

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I am trying to automate some stuff for Mercurial with Powershell.

This has got to be an issue with how I call "hg.exe" and not with Mercurial itself, but I am unable to get it working.

I would like to execute a `hg clone` with some parameters I construct at runtime in Powershell. So far I am doing this:

```
$SourceRepo = "http://some.url.com/where.i.have.a.repo"
$TargetRepo = "d:\path\to\local\copy"
hg clone $SourceRepo $TargetRepo
```

The problem is, that http://some.url.com requires authentication. When running the script, I ask the user for username and password. Assume I have them stored in `$Username` and `$Password` respectively.

I can pass authentication data to Mercurial using `--config`. I then build a string like so

```
$hgAuth = "--config auth.x.prefix=* --config auth.x.username=$Username --config auth.x.password=$Password --config auth.x.schemes=http
```

And so I call my script like so:

```
hg clone $SourceRepo $TargetRepo $hgAuth
```

But Mercurial aborts with an error, saying:

```
hg : hg clone: option --config auth.x.prefix not recognized
```

If I do not use those variables, but instead write the same identical command in powershell as plain text and run it, it works as expected.

So I guess there must be a different way for me to pass the parameters to hg. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `$hgAuth = "--config", "auth.x.prefix=*", "--config", "auth.x.username=$Username", "--config", "auth.x.password=$Password", "--config", "auth.x.schemes=http"`

Comment: This made it work. Wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: When I run that, powershell just hangs as if its waiting for a username/pass but doesn't indicate this in any way shape or form

Comment: Then maybe your username and/or password are wrong and hg reverts to interactive authentication. Try adding --noninteractive as parameter and see what happens. This should force hg to never request interactive authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above, I had to split it into an Array.

@PetSerAl: I don't know why you did not post it as an answer, so I'll post it as one here myself.

It works when done like this:

```
$hgAuth = "--config", "auth.x.prefix=*", "--config", "auth.x.username=$Username", "--config", "auth.x.password=$Password", "--config", "auth.x.schemes=http"
```